# Format a partition stil working after 2 weeks

Tags: gparted, ntfs

I'm trying to format a partition large 185 gb using gparted on an usb pendrive, but it's still working after 2 weeks... it's normal or my program chashes. The last voice of the list says "creation new file system ntfs" and still doing. Help i don't know what to do...

Comment: 185 GB on a pendrive? Did you maybe buy one of those bogus 1TB or 2TB Chinese drives that don't work?

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean that your machine has been trying to format a 185GB for 2 weeks none stop? If this is the case GParted has crashed as any formating program should do this job in a few hours at most. Swtcich of your system & try again. If you get the same problem, you should investigate:
1- Run some tests on your hard disk (Here are 2 free toolkits that will help you:
A- Hiren's boot CD, http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/
B- Ultimate boot CD, http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/ultimate_boot_cd_(ubcd).html)
2- Read GParted help on memory requirements, etc. 
3- Seek help from GParted's manufacturers, if needed.
Good luck.

Comment: Hiren's boot cd is a collection of pirated software. Please keep to the Stack Exchange policy and avoid linking this kind of stuff.